# Can I upgrade a Windows 7 student licence to Windows 10?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, upgrade, windows-10-upgrade, license

I have a Windows 7 with a student license (it's a full license, not OEM). I want to use the free upgrade to Windows 10 and still have a valid license.

The thing is, I am **no longer a student**.

Reinstalling my Windows 7 has never been a problem (including activating it). But I fear that upgrading to Windows 10 could lead to my license being detected as invalid, and being cancelled. Or maybe I'll be asked to get a new "key" from my university (which I cannot do anymore, since I graduated).

Another point of concern: 
So far I have always used the same computer when reinstalling. However, now I am also **changing to a new computer** (old one's broken). The activation process will probably involve more steps.

Is it safe to upgrade?

Comment: Technically: **Yes**;  Legally: **No**;  Legally speaking, per the EULA for the student license you shouldn't even use the Windows 7 license since you are no longer a student.  What version of Windows 7 are you specifically using?  If you are getting a new computer you should format your current PC, install Windows 7 on the new PC, and upgrade that to Windows 10 before July 29th 2015 if you want the free upgrade.

Comment: @Ramhound you should edit your comment and alter the date. I assume you mean 2016? :)

Comment: Its been more then 5 minutes.  Its not worth it to me to delete and submit again, the correct date is well known (July 29th 2016)

Comment: @Ramhound I'm not so sure there would definitely be a EULA restriction on the basis of no longer being a student. Speaking from personal experience, I had received a few licenses under the [Microsoft Campus Agreement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Campus_Agreement) from my alma mater, and I specifically remember acknowledging that upon graduation, the licenses were mine to keep.

Comment: There is a difference between a Student license which was simply discounted and say a license you received through say Dreamspark.  The user themselves is worried about the student license, I presume they know, the terms themselves  I don't have access to a copy).  I am not a lawyer so anyone taking legal advice from me, well, needs a lawyer.  I only learned enough about contract law, when I got my MBA, to know when I need a lawyer.  *EULA more or less falls into that realm*   Microsoft does not "revoke" licenses in normal situations so the fear of it being revoked is unwarranted anyways

Comment: "Upon graduation, students can typically receive perpetual licenses for the purchased software."  This might be a comment but if it exists within the license itself, it would mean the perpetual license isn't automatic, and must be specifically requested.  The precise wording of statements in a legal document is very important.

Comment: The question is whether Microsoft will realize that the license is invalid upon upgrading to Windows 10, and revoke it. (upgrading while also changing the machine) That's assuming that the license is, in fact, not valid anymore. The student license in question specifically states that it's only valid while the user is still a student. However, it's not managed/tracked actively and that allowed multiple reinstallations on the same machine after graduation.
Thanks for the replies so far. Could you reflect on this side of the question?

Comment: I'm still wondering why licensing and legal questions are not closed as OT [Where can I ask about Software Licenses/Licensing?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/165980/201151)
[What is the place to ask about legal issues associated with using software?](http://meta.superuser.com/q/5908/172747)